# SASS nesting multiple classes in one element

Tags: sass

Let's say I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="parent__son parent__son--red"></div>
   <div class="parent__son parent__son--yellow"></div>
   <div class="parent__son parent__son--red parent__son--yellow" ></div>
</div>
```

Parent has 3 sons - first with 'red', second with 'yellow', third with both.

Now I want to do this nesting SCSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;

   &__son {
     width: 20%;

     &--red {
       background: red;
     }
     &--yellow {
       background: yellow;
     }
   }
}
```

Now I want that son that has both red and yellow will has background orange.
How can I write this in SASS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit of Sass Ampersand magic will get you there.

> The interpolation brackets #{ } are needed as two touching ampersands
>   are invalid Sass

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;

   &__son {
     width: 20%;

     &--red {
       background: red;
     }
     &--yellow {
       background: yellow;
     }
     &--yellow#{&}--red { 
        background: orange; 
     }
   }
}
```

[Live Example][https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LMazWK]

Comment: I edited father to parent, thanks, so you can edit your answer too :)

Comment: @TamarG I have added an example of it working, please see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LMazWK